# How can I get the images in my carousel to center?

Tags: css, carousel

I have an image carousel with images in it, and I can't figure out why the images won't centre within it. Here's what I currently have for my CSS as it relates to the content of the carousel:

```
.blueimp-gallery { width: 90%; height: 90%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; align: center;}
```

Normally when the height and width are set to 100% the images fill up the carousel all the way and are centred within it. However I don't want them to be 100%, and when I change them to a smaller amount they align to the top left of the carousel instead of the middle. How can I fix this?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Image is inline element, just add `display: block; margin: auto;` to images :)

Comment: just a easier way to center things with margin and minify css - margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be certain I would need more code, but it seems you're applying your CSS to the gallery, not the images in it...

if you change `.blueimp-gallery` to `.blueimp-gallery img` it should center the images